# Executing commands remotely on few servers and running elapsed timer while running

Tags: bash, shell, ssh

I'm trying to write a script that will execute commands on few servers and display a elapsed time while they are running .

Here is my code , that doesn't really work...

```
echo "Starting..."  
server_num=4
cnt=1
SECONDS=0
for ((i=1; i<=$server_num; i++)) ;do
    read -r pid[$i] < <(
        ssh server$i 'nohup "yes | yes | command" > logfile & echo $!'
        )
    echo
    while kill -0 ${pid[@]} 2> /dev/null; do
        sleep 1
        duration=$SECONDS
        echo -n "Please wait... $(($duration / 60)) minutes and $(($duration % 60)) seconds elapsed." $'\r'
        let cnt=cnt+1
        done
    done
wait
sleep 5
echo "completed..."
```

What am I doing wrong ? I'm getting the pid's of the commands executed , but it seems they are not being executed on the hosts.

Comment: How about [`parallel --bar`](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html) or similar to save yourself some trouble?

Comment: What are you trying to do with `yes | yes | command` ?

Comment: Don't write to `$SECONDS`! Use `Started=$SECONDS` and `duration=$((SECONDS-Started))`

Comment: Thanks , I was not aware of parallel , will check it and try it.

Comment: yes answers with "yes" on a question that command is requesting.

Comment: actually I'm using duration=$SECONDS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue with the script is that background jobs are started on remote systems but checking for progress is done locally.
Writing such a script is not easy because there are many issues to consider (ex. local commands, remote command duration, network latency, connection problems, command outputs, reusable pid's etc.,)
Everybody writes such scripts at one point in their career and everybody learns from them, so I tried to correct your script in 2 ways, maintaining your the idea and removing some unnecessary things so you might also improve your knowledge.

Version 1: execute commands on remote servers and keep the connection opened in a background job. Once the command is started on all hosts then loop while the number of jobs is greater then 0, displaying the message repeating every second.
    Pro: shorter code with easy check
    Con: if network breaks during execution the jobs will be interrupted.

```
server_num=4
SECONDS=0
echo "Starting..."
# Start jobs in background wich will execute remote commands that take long
for ((i=1; i<=$server_num; i++)); do
    ssh server$i "sleep 5" &
done
# Now check the progress until all finish
while [[ $(jobs | wc -l) -gt 0 ]]; do
    echo "Please wait... $(jobs | wc -l) jobs still running... $((SECONDS/60)) minutes and $((SECONDS%60)) seconds elapsed."
    sleep 1
    jobs >/dev/null 2>&1
done
echo "completed..."
```

Version 2: start the jobs on remote servers in background closing the connection right after start but keeping the PID of the job for each host. Then loop while the counter of running jobs is greater then 0, each time connect to each host and check if the process with the saved PID is still alive, if yes then increment the counter and finally display a message.
   Pro: no persistent connection needs to be kept open (in case network breaks the jobs are safe.
   Con: if on a host the job will finish then the checking is still performed on that host (if PID is reused in the meantime the script might take longer checking for wrong thing).

```
server_num=4
SECONDS=0
echo "Starting..."
# Start jobs on remote hosts in background wich will take long
for ((i=1; i<=$server_num; i++)); do
    # save the process ID for each case
    pid[$i]=$(ssh server$i 'nohup bash -c "sleep 12" >logfile 2>&1 & echo $!')
done
# Now check the progress on each host untill all jobs finish
count=${#pid[@]}
while [[ $count -gt 0 ]]; do
    count=0
    for ((i=1; i<=$server_num; i++)); do
        # remotely check if the process id is still in use
        ssh server$i ps -p ${pid[$i]} >/dev/null 2>&1
        if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]; then
            ((count=count+1))
        fi
    done
    echo "Please wait... $count jobs still running... $((SECONDS/60)) minutes and $((SECONDS%60)) seconds elapsed."
    sleep 1
done
echo "completed..."
```

if you would use such scripts for real work, then you will discover other issues that you can correct. Eventually the recommendation is to use other tools that are specifically built to handle such tasks (parallels, dsh etc.)
Good luck!

Comment: Really appreciate your detailed explanation ! Thanks a lot ! This becomes the answer mark.